# Use webdriver on modified DOM, not page source HTML

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access listing at a real estate website with selenium webdriver.  However, when I go to the websites and view page source html, the properties are not listed there, only the JS script sources are.  Only when I inspect elements and see the changes that JS made can I see the properties.  How can I use webdriver to use this version of the page source rather than the default one?

Comment: Relevant? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_WebDriver_fails_to_find_elements_/_Does_not_block_on_page_loa

Answer (score 1):

Selenium WebDriver by default uses the DOM, not the original page source.

So, what you are asking for is already there.